# C++ - How to delete shared_ptr from vector based on it's value

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following class:

```
public:
    Client(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
    {
    }
    void start();
    int connectionId;
```

Than I have the following vector:

```
class Server {
public:
    Server();
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> Clients;
}
```

EDIT*

Can I do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Server::Clients.size(); ++i) {
    if(Server::Clients[i]->connectionId == connectionId)
        Server::Clients.erase(Server::Clients.begin()+i);
}
```

My question is how can I remove the shared pointer in `Clients` with a specific `connectionId` aka remove by value?

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, you can do use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). The following should work.

```
#include <algorithm>

Server &s = /* <getServerFromSomewhere> */;
auto new_end = remove_if(s.Clients.begin(), s.Clients.end(),
    [] (std::shared_ptr<Client>& p) {
        return p->connectionId == /* <someValueToBeRemoved> */;
    }
);
s.Clients.resize(new_end - s.Clients.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::remove_if` with a lambda as predicate and then container's method `erase`:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Client>> Clients;
int id{0}; // the id to be removed
Clients.erase(std::remove_if(Clients.begin(), Clients.end(), [id](const auto &entity) { return id == entity->connectionId; }), Clients.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to `std::remove_if`, you have to fall back to loop of a kind:

```
auto it = Clients.begin()

while (it != Clients.end())
{
    if((*it)->connectionId = testValue)
    {
         // can connection id be non-unique?
         it = Clients.erase(it);
         //if yes, we have to save new iterator
         continue;
    }
    it++;
}
```

If  `connectionId` is unique use find_if to find that element and erase it, it's way cheaper.

If `remove_if` available, following code is possible, if it's advantage over first example is questionable.

```
auto new_end = remove_if(s.Clients.begin(), s.Clients.end(),
    [=] (auto& ptr) {
        return ptr->connectionId ==  testValue; /* value to be removed */
    }
erase(new_end, Clients.end()); // remove tail of vector that is now consisting of empty elements.
```

`Clients` better be a `deque` than a vector, that way erasing an element from it won't cause  the "tail" part of `Clients` list to be copied when every removal is done.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question. Can I go as I marked in the question?

Comment: "both remove an element" - No, they don't both remove an element. The vector's size remains **the same** if just using `remove`. There's a reason the idiom is called "erase-remove".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica he's not doing that, he strangely does in backward loop

Comment: No, he *is* doing that. The loop is another oddity, but he did *try* to use the idiom correctly. Saying something like *"why you use both remove_if and erase? Both remove an element"* is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Guys I have updated my question. Can I correctly remove from a vector like I have described in the question?

Comment: Plus i've changed my vector to `deque` as @Swift-FridayPie suggested. Seems like operators for adding and removing from `deque` and `vector` are pretty much the same.

Comment: @VenelinVasilev the interface is similar, deque got cheaper [] operator than list and  cheaper removal than vector. It only  doesn't have adjacent memory storages for elements

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica sorry, I didn't saw he added second argument to `erase` (or were those consequent edits?). That would be a bug of different kind and a really easy to make mistake.